# Getting name of not checked radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the value of the not checked radio button.

This is my code:

```
<input type="radio" name="myradios" value="rad1" checked="checked" />
<input type="radio" name="myradios" value="rad2" />
<script>
   var notchecked = $('input:radio[name=myradios]:not(checked)');
   console.log(notchecked.val())
</script>
```

But it gives me `rad1`, instead of `rad2`.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fsj1hm2g/

Comment: Use `:not(:checked)` instead

Comment: `:not(checked)` is targeting all coincidences that haven't got a `<checked>` tag (that doesn't exist), but `:not(:checked)` is targetting all coincidencias that haven't got the `:checked`  state, so that's different!

Comment: @haim770: Thank you! If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to correctly use the `:checked` selector:

```
$('input:radio[name=myradios]:not(:checked)');
```

See [Documetation](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `var notchecked = $('input:radio[name=myradios]:not(:checked)');` instead of `:not(checked)`